# Sumar un mes por cada iteración

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Hola amigos quiero sumar 1 mes por cada iteración como puedo hacer eso.

```
  let currentDate = new Date(); 
    for (let i = 0; i < lean.dues; i++) {
      
       currentDate.setMonth(currentDate.getMonth() + i + 1);
      await PayModel.create({
        datePay: currentDate,
        pay: totalPay / lean.dues + parseFloat(admon.admon),
        lateInterest: 0,
        latePayment: 0,
        interest: bail,
        leanId: lean.id,
        status: PayStatus.NOT_AVAILABLE,
      });
    }
```

la idea es que se le sume 1 mes por cada iteración asi generar dia actual pero con meses diferente ejemplo si es enero quiero que la iteración llegue hasta junio si son 5 iteraciones

Me pasa esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

```
  for (let i = 0; i < lean.dues; i++) {
    const currentDate = new Date(); // Obtener la fecha actual
    currentDate.setMonth(currentDate.getMonth() + 1); // Sumar 1 mes
  
    const nextDate = new Date(currentDate); // Crear una nueva instancia de fecha
    nextDate.setMonth(nextDate.getMonth() + i); // Sumar i meses adicionales
  
    await PayModel.create({
      datePay: nextDate,
      pay: totalPay / lean.dues + parseFloat(admon.admon),
      lateInterest: 0,
      latePayment: 0,
      interest: bail,
      leanId: lean.id,
      status: PayStatus.NOT_AVAILABLE,
    });
  }
```

esta es la solución, si le sirve a alguien.

Comment: EL primer let y la asignación son innecesarios. Dentro del for defines la variable como const y tiene otro scope, son una variable diferente.

Comment: gracias hare eso

Answer (score 1):

Pasa que estas haciendo esto:

```js
let valor =0;

for(let i=0; i<10; i++){
  valor = valor +i;
  console.log(valor);
}
```

Es decir a la variable "valor" (en tu caso la fecha) le  vuelves a sumas el valor.

Lo que tu quieres es algo como esto:

```js
let valor =0;

for(let i=0; i<10; i++){
  valor = valor + 1;
  console.log(valor);
}
```

Es decir solo sumar +1

```js
const currentDate = new Date(); 
//for (let i = 0; i < lean.dues; i++) 
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

     currentDate.setMonth(currentDate.getMonth() + 1);
    //await PayModel.create({
    //  datePay: currentDate,
    //  pay: totalPay / lean.dues + parseFloat(admon.admon),
    //  lateInterest: 0,
    //  latePayment: 0,
    //  interest: bail,
    //  leanId: lean.id,
    //  status: PayStatus.NOT_AVAILABLE,
    //});
    
    console.log(currentDate)
  }
```

Comment: Usa `const` en vez de `let`, la variable no la estás re-asignando, será siempre un objeto de fecha. Saludos